# Accents not getting inserted in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, character-encoding, nvarchar, non-ascii-characters

I am trying to add this name -> NumāTwó into a table in MS sql server along with the accents. But it is only getting inserted as -> NumaTwó (without ā). I tried many encodings but doesn't seem to work. I have given the DDL of the table below. Please help

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [testname] [nvarchar](40) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

----------- Insert-----------
insert into test values ('NumāTwó');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `N` as Prefix for [Unicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180059.aspx) character

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [testname] [nvarchar](40) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI NULL
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

----------- Insert-----------
insert into test values (N'NumāTwó');
```

Comment: @Sindu_ glad it helps you

Answer (score 3):

Try to use N before the string while inserting like this:

```
insert into test values (N'NumāTwó');
```