# Sql Server Management Studio converts Turkish Chars To English on insert

Tags: sql-server

Assume that I have a query like:

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(SomeCol) Values('ışç');
```

It succesfully inserts. But when i execute a select query for it, I get:

```
isc
```

My team mates don't have this problem. I also don't have this problem when I do this through the app I'm developing.

I guess it is about my management studio collation. I tried to find a menu to change it but I was not able to.

Comment: make sure `N` as prefix for unicode this will solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391071

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I should remember it. It will get me going but it is still a workaround.